# iframes + css + validation

Tags: html, css

I have this iframe in use:

```
 <iframe src="includes/captcha/display_captcha.php" id="captcha" scrolling="no" marginheight="0"></iframe>
```

Validation fails on scrolling and marginheight - everyone knows these are now obsolete.

I have tried & google searched all sorts of solutions to switch these inline formating into CSS but nothing works in all browsers.

You can see the captcha image here (from above) - www.flirtwithme.co - if you interested.

Is it possible to replace these 2 commands successfully in CSS and control the iframe or is this just not possible yet?

thankyou

Comment: What version of HTML are you validating against?

Comment: using firefix 'developer tools' local validator - "Errors found while checking this document as HTML5!" - thus I assume html5...

Comment: Didn't get your question. Could you explain?

Comment: sure - on this site - www.flirtwithme.co I'm building a site. The captcha is being displayed using an iframe. I've found if I include scrolling and marginheight inline with the iframe it will sit correctly (eg: no scrolling etc) in all the browsers I've checked. the only catch is these 2 values don't validate - using firefox validator. I've tried to remove this inline formatting and change to  CSS but I can't find replacements that work in all the browers if at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to be valid HTML5 you want seamless.  see http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_iframe_tag.cfm

```
<iframe src="includes/captcha/display_captcha.php" id="captcha" height="100" width="50" seamless></iframe>
```

This is not currently supported by any browsers so for functionality you must keep using invalid attributes until browsers catch up to the standard.

Comment: Tried seemless but the validator said its not support by many of the browers yet...

Comment: `seamless` is the way to do it if you want to be valid html5 (although not supported by anyone yet).  `scrolling="no" marginheight="0"` is the way to do it for it to work.  Validation will be broken until browsers are valid.

Comment: You can follow to see when browsers adopt it here: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_iframe_seamless.asp